# golang: cross platform path.Dir

Tags: windows, path, go

I'd like to use `path.Dir()` on Unix and Windows with a platform specific directory. Please take a look at the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`path.Dir("a/b/c"): `, path.Dir("a/b/c"))
    fmt.Println(`path.Dir("c:\foo\bar.exe"): `, path.Dir(`c:\foo\bar.exe`))
}
```

This outputs

```
path.Dir("a/b/c"):  a/b
path.Dir("c:\foo\bar.exe"):  .
```

I'd like to get for the second call to `path.Dir()` (windows) something like

```
c:\foo
```

Is it possible to tell `path.dir()` to use Windows separators for my program running on windows? Or should I always convert the backslashes `\`  to forward slashes (`/`)? What is the preferred strategy here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see where the "problem" is. [This discussion at golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/UoRlbaSqtDk/discussion) gave me the hint, that `path.Dir()` always uses `/` and `filepath.Dir()` is the function to be used for platform dependent manipulation.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`filepath.Dir("a/b/c"): `, filepath.Dir("a/b/c"))
    fmt.Println(`filepath.Dir("c:\foo\bar.exe"): `, filepath.Dir(`c:\foo\bar.exe`))
}
```

on windows:

```
filepath.Dir("a/b/c"):  a\b
filepath.Dir("c:\foo\bar.exe"):  c:\foo
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the package overview for 'path' states that it is for slash-separated paths and 'path/filepath' is os-specific.  Also, if you need it, filepath.ToSlash() and filepath.FromSlash() can be used to convert to and from slash-separated and os-specific.

Comment: @RunningWild Good advice, thanks. I, as a non-native speaker, assumed that "slash separated paths" can mean both (back and forward slashes). Now I know better.