# What rules decides the Go package installation location?

Tags: go

When I run `go install` with some of my own package located in `%GOPATH%\src`, it will be installed to `%GOPATH%\pkg`.

I read that `%GOROOT%` and `%GOPATH%` folders have similar organization. So I tried `go install cmd\cgo` with the `%GOROOT%\src\cmd\cgo` package which is part of the golang installation. But the final `cgo.exe` is installed to `%GOROOT%\pkg\tool\`.

I checked all the `*.go` files in the `cmd\cgo` folder. They all have a `package main` declaration. So I was expecting the final `cgo.exe` to be installed to `%GOROOT%\bin`.

My questions are:

- Why the `cgo.exe` is installed to `pkg` rather than `bin`?
- Where does the `tool` part in the `pkg\tool` come from? Can I do similar thing for my own package?

Comment: That's how the go tool works and you cannot do this for your own code. The stdlib and the std tools are treated differently.

Comment: Related: [Why is there no binary created when running `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118766/why-is-there-no-binary-created-when-running-go-get-golang-org-x-tools-cmd-godoc/33119819#33119819)

Answer (score 3):

The [`go build`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) command relies on a go tool directory, where build tools are installed (`compile.exe`, `link.exe`, ...).

And `ToolDir` is defined as:

```
var ToolDir = filepath.Join(runtime.GOROOT(), "pkg/tool/"+runtime.GOOS+"_"+runtime.GOARCH)
```

So any build tool is in `%GOROOT%\pkg\tool\`

Comment: How does Go handle the translation between `/` and ` \ `?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet with https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#FromSlash. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12132445/6309

Comment: If in doubt, use forward slash '/' which works on POSIX file systems including Windows.